# How to (or should I) utilize caching in serving local content from a chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, caching, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app

Background:

I hope this question isn't too broad, but I haven't seen much discussion of this point.

I have a chrome extension with the following simple architecture: a background page triggers a popup. at extensionRoot/popup/index.html.  That popup loads several resources out of the /popup/ directory, which includes a few images, a single css file, and a single large javascript file.

The large javascript file has been cleaned up with closure compiler, which cut its size by about 30% and then fed through an obfusucator which increased its size by about 15%.

**Question:**

Aside from optimizing the code itself, what other steps should I take to speed up the time it takes chrome to render the popup?

I'm most interested in whether there are any steps I'm missing that "cache" the popup. Caching has always been a bit of a mystery to me.  I get that in this instance, the code is locally accessible and therefore caching wouldn't serve its normal purpose of speeding up file transfer time.  But is there some step I should be taking to keep the file "hot" or "live" or "loaded" in chrome's memory?

I know this is a bit pedantic - but load time is absolutely crucial to my application.  And I imagine other people have similar questions.

Comment: A delay of 100ms in UI action is considered to be instantaneous. What are you numbers? The general rule of thumb is to optimize only when it's really needed and start by [profiling](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/profile/rendering-tools/analyze-runtime) to see where the bottlenecks are, in order not to guess blindly.

Comment: Its hard for me to understand what I'm reading with this.  Here are my [results](http://imgur.com/Y8chTpD)

Comment: That docs page explains all this stuff in detail. As for your screenshot, it covers 1.2 seconds, but it's not clear when was the moment you invoked the popup. See also https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/profile/evaluate-performance/timeline-tool

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is evidence that Chrome caches extension JS files, since changing them without express extension reload will often not have any effect. So you're not "missing" anything, and you mostly cannot affect it anyway since you can't set caching directives.

If you find yourself in a situation where loading some big chunk of code in the popup is a problem (because it recreates the popup every time), you can create a [persistent background page](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/background_pages) (not an Event page) instead, load your code there, and have the popup call the background page. This way, you eliminate the load time for the popup. **Be mindful if the code depends on `document`/`window` during its initialization - then this approach won't work.**

You can either [pass messages](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging) to the background page to let it do stuff, or you can directly access JS code through [`chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage()`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/extension#method-getBackgroundPage).

```
// background page
var myBigFatCodeObject = ...; // Loads once at extension load

// popup
var myBigFatCodeObject = chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage().myBigFatCodeObject;
// Use myBigFatCodeObject as normal
```

Note: this is very old-school and will expressly fail with [Event pages](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/event_pages). But for this very specific optimization, this can be useful.

As mentioned, any `document`/`window`-specific initialization that happens in this "shared" code will refer to the background page. **This can lead to failures if it's a UI library.**

Decoupling the code by using message-based communication is better from design perspective, but messaging is asynchronous and has an overhead.